# Rotating Particle - Violation of Einstein Equivalence Principle

Tags: general-relativity, inertial-frames, equivalence-principle

How does adding rotation to a freely falling particle violate the Einstein equivalence principle?

I realize there is a similar post here:

[An example of a theory that respects the Weak Equivalence Principle but violates the Einstein Equivalence Principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252905/an-example-of-a-theory-that-respects-the-weak-equivalence-principle-but-violates)

but I failed to understand the response after reading it a number of times.

Comment: Just to clear, because I have a related question, not an answer, is this the extract that is the problem for you  _We could imagine a theory of gravity in which freely falling particles begin to rotate as they moved through a gravitational field. Then they could fall along the same paths as they would in an accelerated frame (thereby satisfying the WEP), but you could nevertheless detect the existence of the gravitational field (in violation of the EEP). Such theories seem contrived, but there is no law of nature that forbids them._

Comment: Yes, it's from Carroll.

Comment: Wouldn't the gravitational field have to have torsion for this to happen, if it was GR?

Comment: Could you explain more please @Bob?